# Slow SQL Response in MariaDB on selecting an extra column

Tags: mysql, mariadb, response-time

Notice the following two queries, difference between them is highlighted

Query A :

```
SELECT  tasks.TaskID, tasks.CardID, tasks.CritPath, tasks.ReworkCount,
        cs.WorkflowID,
         cs.StageCode,    -- This is added
        tasks.CurrentEscalationLevel,
        tasks.Title, tasks.Description, tasks.EscalationDelay,
        tasks.StartDate, tasks.EndDate, tasks.OriginalStartDate,
        tasks.OriginalEndDate, tasks.Priority, tasks.Duration,
        tasks.Status
    FROM  Tasks tasks
    INNER JOIN  CardsSettings cs  ON cs.CardID = tasks.TaskID
    INNER JOIN  
    (
        SELECT  t1.WorkflowID
            FROM  
            (
                SELECT  WorkflowID
                    from  Workflow
                    Where  IsWFActive = "YES"
                      and  LastUpdatedDateTime BETWEEN "2018-11-21 23:59:59" AND "2019-11-21 23:59:59"
                      AND  WorkflowTypeID = 9
            ) t1
            INNER JOIN  
            (
                SELECT  formSubCardSettings.WorkflowID, cfsm.Value as
                    Value
                     FROM  CardsSettings AS formSubCardSettings
                    INNER JOIN  custom_form_submissions cfs  ON cfs.FormSubmissionID = formSubCardSettings.CardID
                      AND  cfs.IsHistory = 'NO'
                    INNER JOIN  custom_form cf  ON cf.FormID = cfs.FormID
                    INNER JOIN  custom_form_metadata cfm  ON cfm.FormID = cf.FormID
                    INNER JOIN  custom_form_submissions_metadata cfsm  ON cfsm.FormSubmissionID = cfs.FormSubmissionID
                      AND  cfsm.FormMetaID = cfm.FormMetaID
                    INNER JOIN  Workflow cfwf  ON cfwf.WorkflowID = formSubCardSettings.WorkflowID
                    WHERE  cf.FormTitle = "Project Initiation"
                      AND  cfm.FieldLabel = "wid"
                      AND  cfwf.WorkflowTypeID = 9
                      AND  (cfsm.Value IN("413"))) t2  ON t1.WorkflowID = t2.WorkflowID
    ) a  ON a.WorkflowID = cs.WorkflowID;
```

Query B :

> SELECT  tasks.TaskID, tasks.CardID, tasks.CritPath, tasks.ReworkCount,
>   cs.WorkflowID, tasks.CurrentEscalationLevel, tasks.Title,
>   tasks.Description, tasks.EscalationDelay,  tasks.StartDate,
>   tasks.EndDate, tasks.OriginalStartDate, tasks.OriginalEndDate,
>   tasks.Priority, tasks.Duration, tasks.Status FROM  Tasks tasks  INNER
>   JOIN CardsSettings cs  ON  cs.CardID = tasks.TaskID INNER JOIN (
>   SELECT t1.WorkflowID FROM (SELECT WorkflowID from Workflow Where
>   IsWFActive = "YES" and LastUpdatedDateTime BETWEEN "2018-11-21
>   23:59:59" and "2019-11-21 23:59:59" AND WorkflowTypeID = 9) t1  INNER
>   JOIN ( SELECT formSubCardSettings.WorkflowID, cfsm.Value as Value FROM
>   CardsSettings AS formSubCardSettings  INNER JOIN
>   custom_form_submissions cfs ON cfs.FormSubmissionID =
>   formSubCardSettings.CardID AND cfs.IsHistory = 'NO'  INNER JOIN
>   custom_form cf ON cf.FormID = cfs.FormID  INNER JOIN
>   custom_form_metadata cfm ON cfm.FormID = cf.FormID   INNER JOIN
>   custom_form_submissions_metadata cfsm ON cfsm.FormSubmissionID =
>   cfs.FormSubmissionID  AND cfsm.FormMetaID = cfm.FormMetaID  INNER JOIN
>   Workflow cfwf ON cfwf.WorkflowID = formSubCardSettings.WorkflowID 
>   WHERE  cf.FormTitle = "Project Initiation" AND cfm.FieldLabel = "wid"
>   AND cfwf.WorkflowTypeID = 9  AND (cfsm.Value IN("413"))) t2   ON
>   t1.WorkflowID = t2.WorkflowID) a ON a.WorkflowID = cs.WorkflowID;

The column **StageCode** is a varchar(1024).

I have exact same database and schema on two separate DB engines, one is mysql (5.6) and another is mariadb (10.4)

Running the Queries on mariadb resulted in very different response times:

> Query A : Approx 5 seconds
>
> Query B : Approx 0.2 seconds

Just by adding an extra field from cs, response times are increasing many fold. This is not a one off behavior, as its happening every time. Also notice that both queries have cs.WorkflowID selected.

Running the above queries on mysql results in quick responses, both return in less than 0.1 seconds.

The explain for the problematic query A on both DB engines is as follows:

mysql:

```
+----+-------------+---------------------+--------+----------------------------+------------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------+-------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table               | type   | possible_keys              | key              | key_len | ref                                                  | rows  | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------------------+--------+----------------------------+------------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | tasks               | ALL    | PRIMARY                    | NULL             | NULL    | NULL                                                 |  3091 | NULL        |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | cs                  | eq_ref | PRIMARY,FK_CS_WFID_WF_WFID | PRIMARY          | 4       | zestlTitan_3000037868.tasks.TaskID                   |     1 | Using where |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>          | ref    | <auto_key0>                | <auto_key0>      | 4       | zestlTitan_3000037868.cs.WorkflowID                  |    10 | Using index |
|  2 | DERIVED     | <derived3>          | ALL    | NULL                       | NULL             | NULL    | NULL                                                 |    81 | NULL        |
|  2 | DERIVED     | <derived4>          | ref    | <auto_key0>                | <auto_key0>      | 5       | t1.WorkflowID                                        |   715 | NULL        |
|  4 | DERIVED     | cfs                 | ALL    | PRIMARY,FormID             | NULL             | NULL    | NULL                                                 | 17888 | Using where |
|  4 | DERIVED     | cf                  | eq_ref | PRIMARY                    | PRIMARY          | 4       | zestlTitan_3000037868.cfs.FormID                     |     1 | Using where |
|  4 | DERIVED     | formSubCardSettings | eq_ref | PRIMARY,FK_CS_WFID_WF_WFID | PRIMARY          | 4       | zestlTitan_3000037868.cfs.FormSubmissionID           |     1 | Using where |
|  4 | DERIVED     | cfwf                | eq_ref | PRIMARY,FK_WTID_WFT_WTID   | PRIMARY          | 4       | zestlTitan_3000037868.formSubCardSettings.WorkflowID |     1 | Using where |
|  4 | DERIVED     | cfsm                | ref    | FormSubmissionID           | FormSubmissionID | 4       | zestlTitan_3000037868.cfs.FormSubmissionID           |     4 | Using where |
|  4 | DERIVED     | cfm                 | eq_ref | PRIMARY,FormID             | PRIMARY          | 4       | zestlTitan_3000037868.cfsm.FormMetaID                |     1 | Using where |
|  3 | DERIVED     | Workflow            | ref    | FK_WTID_WFT_WTID           | FK_WTID_WFT_WTID | 4       | const                                                |    81 | Using where |
+----+-------------+---------------------+--------+----------------------------+------------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------+-------+-------------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

On mariadb:

```
+------+-------------+---------------------+--------+----------------------------+--------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------------+------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table               | type   | possible_keys              | key                | key_len | ref                                              | rows | Extra       |
+------+-------------+---------------------+--------+----------------------------+--------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------------+------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | tasks               | ALL    | PRIMARY                    | NULL               | NULL    | NULL                                             | 3072 |             |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | cs                  | eq_ref | PRIMARY,FK_CS_WFID_WF_WFID | PRIMARY            | 4       | zestlTitan_3000037868.tasks.TaskID               | 1    | Using where |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | Workflow            | eq_ref | PRIMARY,FK_WTID_WFT_WTID   | PRIMARY            | 4       | zestlTitan_3000037868.cs.WorkflowID              | 1    | Using where |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | cfwf                | eq_ref | PRIMARY,FK_WTID_WFT_WTID   | PRIMARY            | 4       | zestlTitan_3000037868.cs.WorkflowID              | 1    | Using where |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | formSubCardSettings | ref    | PRIMARY,FK_CS_WFID_WF_WFID | FK_CS_WFID_WF_WFID | 5       | zestlTitan_3000037868.cs.WorkflowID              | 219  | Using index |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | cfs                 | eq_ref | PRIMARY,FormID             | PRIMARY            | 4       | zestlTitan_3000037868.formSubCardSettings.CardID | 1    | Using where |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | cf                  | eq_ref | PRIMARY                    | PRIMARY            | 4       | zestlTitan_3000037868.cfs.FormID                 | 1    | Using where |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | cfsm                | ref    | FormSubmissionID           | FormSubmissionID   | 4       | zestlTitan_3000037868.formSubCardSettings.CardID | 4    | Using where |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | cfm                 | eq_ref | PRIMARY,FormID             | PRIMARY            | 4       | zestlTitan_3000037868.cfsm.FormMetaID            | 1    | Using where |
+------+-------------+---------------------+--------+----------------------------+--------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------------+------+-------------+
9 rows in set (0.002 sec)
```

Can someone identify what is going wrong? Both machines have similar resources (RAM/Disk)

**EDIT 1:**

The same weird behavior manifests if instead of StageCode(Varchar 1024), I use another CardsSettings(cs) field which is tinyint or int(10). So I doubt this has to do with long columns. However, there are a couple Text columns in the CardsSettings table, along with couple of varchar(1024) and a varchar(4096).

**EDIT 2:**

The subquery for t2 if queried separately takes just 0.05 sec:

```
SELECT formSubCardSettings.WorkflowID FROM CardsSettings AS formSubCardSettings INNER JOIN custom_form_submissions cfs ON cfs.FormSubmissionID = formSubCardSettings.CardID AND cfs.IsHistory = 'NO' INNER JOIN custom_form cf ON cf.FormID = cfs.FormID INNER JOIN custom_form_metadata cfm ON cfm.FormID = cf.FormID INNER JOIN custom_form_submissions_metadata cfsm ON cfsm.FormSubmissionID = cfs.FormSubmissionID AND cfsm.FormMetaID = cfm.FormMetaID INNER JOIN Workflow cfwf ON cfwf.WorkflowID = formSubCardSettings.WorkflowID WHERE cf.FormTitle = "Project Initiation" AND cfm.FieldLabel = "wid" AND cfwf.WorkflowTypeID = 9 AND (cfsm.Value IN("413"));
+------------+
| WorkflowID |
+------------+
|        413 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.056 sec)
```

If I simply substitute the entire subquery in the original Query "A", then the Query A becomes:

> MariaDB [zestlTitan_3000037868]> SELECT tasks.TaskID, tasks.CardID,
>   tasks.CritPath, tasks.ReworkCount, cs.WorkflowID, **cs.StageCode**,
>   tasks.CurrentEscalationLevel, tasks.Title, tasks.Description,
>   tasks.EscalationDelay, tasks.StartDate, tasks.EndDate,
>   tasks.OriginalStartDate, tasks.OriginalEndDate, tasks.Priority,
>   tasks.Duration, tasks.Status FROM Tasks tasks INNER JOIN CardsSettings
>   cs ON cs.CardID = tasks.TaskID INNER JOIN ( SELECT t1.WorkflowID FROM
>   (SELECT WorkflowID from Workflow Where IsWFActive = "YES" and
>   LastUpdatedDateTime BETWEEN "2018-11-21 23:59:59" and "2019-11-21
>   23:59:59" AND WorkflowTypeID = 9) t1 INNER JOIN ( **SELECT "413" as
>   WorkflowID**) t2 ON t1.WorkflowID = t2.WorkflowID) a ON a.WorkflowID =
>   cs.WorkflowID;

This is now running very fast on mariadb (~0.1 sec).

**EDIT 3:**

The Edit 2 gave me some clue as to why this may be happening, clearly the subquery t2 was not being computed apriori (I may be wrong). So I modified the query to use WHERE t1.WorkflowID IN (...)t2 instead of the INNER JOIN as follows:

> SELECT tasks.TaskID, tasks.CardID, tasks.CritPath, tasks.ReworkCount,
>   cs.WorkflowID, cs.StageCode, tasks.CurrentEscalationLevel,
>   tasks.Title, tasks.Description, tasks.EscalationDelay,
>   tasks.StartDate, tasks.EndDate, tasks.OriginalStartDate,
>   tasks.OriginalEndDate, tasks.Priority, tasks.Duration, tasks.Status
>   FROM Tasks tasks INNER JOIN CardsSettings cs ON cs.CardID =
>   tasks.TaskID INNER JOIN ( SELECT t1.WorkflowID FROM (SELECT WorkflowID
>   from Workflow Where IsWFActive = "YES" and LastUpdatedDateTime BETWEEN
>   "2018-11-21 23:59:59" and "2019-11-21 23:59:59" AND WorkflowTypeID =
>   9) t1 WHERE t1.WorkflowID IN ( **SELECT formSubCardSettings.WorkflowID
>   FROM CardsSettings AS formSubCardSettings INNER JOIN
>   custom_form_submissions cfs ON cfs.FormSubmissionID =
>   formSubCardSettings.CardID AND cfs.IsHistory = 'NO' INNER JOIN
>   custom_form cf ON cf.FormID = cfs.FormID INNER JOIN
>   custom_form_metadata cfm ON cfm.FormID = cf.FormID INNER JOIN
>   custom_form_submissions_metadata cfsm ON cfsm.FormSubmissionID =
>   cfs.FormSubmissionID AND cfsm.FormMetaID = cfm.FormMetaID INNER JOIN
>   Workflow cfwf ON cfwf.WorkflowID = formSubCardSettings.WorkflowID
>   WHERE cf.FormTitle = "Project Initiation" AND cfm.FieldLabel = "wid"
>   AND cfwf.WorkflowTypeID = 9 AND (cfsm.Value IN("413")))**) a ON
>   a.WorkflowID = cs.WorkflowID;

And now, the mariadb query works quickly as well ~ 0.2 sec.

While through this hit and trial, I've managed to make the query respond quickly, can some one try to make some sense out of this entire thing?

Answer (score 0):

When a row is "too big", some columns' values are written to "off-record" storage.  Rereading the row (`SELECTing`) necessitates fetching from this other place.  If the data is not cached in RAM, then that is another disk hit.  Disk hits take time.

It sounds like the table has lots of columns?  Many are `TEXT` or large `VARCHARs`?  This *may* explain the sluggishness of the first query.

One of the places where MySQL's and MariaDB's Optimizers have diverged is in handling subqueries.

There are two more possible issues with the extra column...

- It is fetch as the second(?) table of the query, and it needs to be hauled around for the rest of the query.
- If an intermediate temp table is needed (can't tell from the `EXPLAIN`) it will probably be forced to be MyISAM, not MEMORY.  This is because of the large `VARCHAR(1024)`, even if the actual data is small.  MyISAM is slower than MEMORY.  (If some other column is 'big', then MyISAM would already be required; so this answer does not apply.)

This construct is especially tricky, and has been dealt with differently:

```
SELECT ...
    FROM ( SELECT ... )
    JOIN ( SELECT ... )
```

MySQL often materializes the derived tables and dynamically decides what index it needs and builds that index.  See `<auto-key>` in the `EXPLAIN`.

MariaDB tackles subqueries in a different way.

There may be indexes that would help.

```
        Where  IsWFActive = "YES"
          and  LastUpdatedDateTime BETWEEN "2018-11-21 23:59:59" AND "2019-11-21 23:59:59"
          AND  WorkflowTypeID = 9
```

needs

```
INDEX(IsWFActive, WorkflowTypeID,   -- in either order
      LastUpdatedDateTime)          -- after the others
```

And:

```
ON a.WorkflowID = cs.WorkflowID
ON cs.CardID = tasks.TaskID
```

needs this so that it can start with the second part, then go back to the first tables:

```
CardsSettings:  INDEX(WorkflowID)
Tasks:          INDEX(TaskID)   -- unless that is the PRIMARY KEY
```

This last suggestion *may* eliminate the "hauling around of big columns" that I mentioned earlier.

**More**

This should make the query run faster in all(?) cases:

```
INDEX(WorkflowID,    -- first
      CardID, StageCode)   -- to make it covering (with or without stage
```

Note that it will encourage the Optimizer to dispense with the derived table first (which is usually optimal), then move to `cs` via `WorkflowID`.  Finally, the rest of the columns needed are included ("covering").

For further discussion, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: CardsSettings has WorkflowID as the Foreign Key into Workflow table, where WorkflowID is the PKEY. Also, TaskID is the Primary Key in Tasks.

Comment: Interestingly enough, the problem happens the moment I add any column from CardsSettings. So even if I add select for a tinyint field in CardsSettings table instead of StageCode, then also it takes a long time. Same goes for an int(10) field. So may be the varchar(1024) is not really the problem?

Comment: @Ouroboros - I added some more.  Note:  It may or may not be possible to include a varchar(1024) in an index.  It may work on 10.4, but fail on 5.6.  What is the `ROW_FORMAT` of the table?